# Truncate part of an NSString starting at a particular character

Tags: string, cocoa-touch, nsstring, truncate

I have a string

```
NSString * myOldString = @"This is a string (and this part is between brackets)"
```

Now, I want to truncate the string in such a way, that basically everything between the brackets, including the brackets, is truncated.

More precisely: I don't care what is happening after the first bracket at all.

I can't do a simple `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:`, because I cannot predict what will be between the brackets. So, the resulting string should be:

```
"This is a string"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method:

```
NSArray *components = [myOldString componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
NSString *newString = [components objectAtIndex:0];
```

Should also work for the case where there isn't a '('

Answer (score 0):

should be simply

```
NSRange r = [myOldString rangeOfString:@"("]
NSString new string = [myOldString substringToIndex:r.location];
```

if the braket is still there just -1

Comment: Thanks, that works, but (see Tom below) I had to build in some extra code to make sure that it didn't go out of bounds if there was no bracket.